# How can I debug a Vim plugin not being loaded?

Tags: vim, plugins, snipmate

I'm trying to use the Vim snipMate plugin, and I've installed it as it directs, but when I press tab nothing happens.

- How can I debug this? Are there log files Vim makes when it tries to load stuff?
- How can I see what plugins its loaded correctly?

I've tried `:sni<tab>` to see if there's anything called snipsomething installed but nothing completes.

In the installation tutorial it doesn't mention adding anything into my `vimrc` but I guess it finds the `/plugin/` dir automatically?

I'm running on Windows and Unix and I have the same profile with the same problem.

Other plugins like NerdTree are loading OK.

**Update:** Following another question, I've tried `:inoremap` and `:snoremap` and the `<Tab>` entry mentioning `TriggerSnippet()` is there:

e.g.

```
s <Tab>   * <Esc>i <Right><C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
```

- Does this mean it's enabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:verbose imap <tab>
```

will tell you what is bound to `<tab>`

`:scriptnames` will tell you what scripts were loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert `echo "Loaded so far"` and the like inside the plugin code - the text will be displayed in the bottom line if the `echo` is executed. Debugging by printf :) Crude, but simple and works.

Also: `plugin` is loaded automagically. `plugins` is not.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `plugin`, I'll change the original post.
I'll try that method now.

Comment: Wow, it never ceases to amaze me how subtle things like this are what bite you.  This is exactly what was preventing my plugins from loading.  I'd named the directory ~/.vim/plugins.  Doh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had something dodgy in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\` directory which was superceding my user preferences. I just blew away that directory and it works now.

Comment: As a follow-up, it seems that using `set runtimepath` to try to link to a shared .vim thing doens't play well with snippets. Maybe there's another thing that needs to be set to get it to work.

For the moment I've just made a soft link on my unix env, from `~/.vim` to the shared one